# How to Bind Two Data Fames with Multiple Columns based on the Column Name in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to bind two data frames which has more than 600 column and each of those 600 columns are unique names.

I want to add the two data frame one below the other based on the column names, I can do it when there are a few columns but I am not sure how to about with it with more than 600 columns as writing the 600 columns names for merge is quite difficult. Can someone help me out?

Attached is the simplified data of both data frame.

This is one of the data frame called pd:

```
structure(list(ds = c("2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", 
"2019-04-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-06-01", "2019-07-01", "2019-08-01", 
"2019-09-01", "2019-10-01", "2019-11-01", "2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", 
"2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", 
"2020-07-01", "2020-08-01", "2020-09-01", "2020-10-01", "2020-11-01", 
"2020-12-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-03-01", "2021-04-01", 
"2021-05-01", "2021-06-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-08-01", "2021-09-01", 
"2021-10-01", "2021-11-01", "2021-12-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-02-01", 
"2022-03-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-05-01", "2022-06-01", "2022-07-01", 
"2022-08-01"), X1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 
85, 72, 111, 96, 50, 95, 48, 87, 75, 249, 173, 74, 86, 127, 209, 
92, 137, 49, 84, 75, 73, 376, 196, 91, 107, 124, 177, 244, 275, 
100, 176), X2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 29, 243, 
281, 262, 283, 0, 264, 104, 289, 41, 76), X3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 157, 171, 377, 409, 375, 314, 253, 322, 
130, 472, 115, 179)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -44L))
```

[image]

This is the other data frame, pd1

```
structure(list(ds = structure(c(19236, 19266, 19297, 19327, 19358, 
19389, 19417, 19448, 19478), class = "Date"), X1 = structure(c(103.045278486668, 
103.045278486668, 103.045278486668, 103.045278486668, 103.045278486668, 
103.045278486668, 103.045278486668, 103.045278486668, 103.045278486668
), tsp = c(2022.66666666667, 2023.33333333333, 12), class = "ts"), 
    X2 = structure(c(9.97152706820806, 9.97152706820806, 9.97152706820806, 
    9.97152706820806, 9.97152706820806, 9.97152706820806, 9.97152706820806, 
    9.97152706820806, 9.97152706820806), tsp = c(2022.66666666667, 
    2023.33333333333, 12), class = "ts"), X3 = structure(c(21.2001463509872, 
    21.2001463509872, 21.2001463509872, 21.2001463509872, 21.2001463509872, 
    21.2001463509872, 21.2001463509872, 21.2001463509872, 21.2001463509872
    ), tsp = c(2022.66666666667, 2023.33333333333, 12), class = "ts")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they have a similar structure, you can simply use `rbind`?

`rbind(pd, pd1)`

Courtesy of @jay.sf in the comments below: The `rbind` function will automatically combine the columns with corresponding names.

Comment: Can this work if the Column names are in different orders, Like One with X1,X2,X3,X4 and the other X4,X2,X3,X1 ? It is imperative that the data gets added only if the columns names are same.

Comment: Yes, as long as you reorder. See the answer by @mri below for that.

Comment: @VvdL No need to reorder, try `df1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4)); df2 <- df1[sample(seq_along(df1))]; rbind(df1, df2)`. `rbind` handles order.

Comment: you are quite correct  :). Good correction, thank you